# Get the stem width (i, T) of a Font in ConTeXt Mk IV

Tags: fonts, context

In the TiKz-Manual it says:

> ... that LaTeX has two commands called \thinlines and \thicklines and that \thinlines gives the line width of “normal” lines, more precisely, of the thickness that, say, the stem of a letter like “T” or “i” has.

Is there a similar command in ConTeXt to get the stem width of i,T of a font?
I would like to have a consistent line width in my MetaPost drawings and the used font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that LaTeX does not use the current width of the stem of `T`; rather it uses `\fontdimen8` of `line10` font which is equal to the width of the stem of `T` *for computer modern fonts*. You can copy the LaTeX definition in ConTeXt

```
\font\tenln  line10   
\font\tenlnw linew10

\newdimen\wholewidth
\newdimen\halfwidth

\def\thinlines
  {\wholewidth\fontdimen8\tenln 
   \halfwidth .5\wholewidth}

\def\thicklines
  {\wholewidth\fontdimen8\tenlnw 
   \halfwidth .5\wholewidth}


\startbuffer[circle]
  draw fullcircle xyscaled (1cm,1cm) withpen pencircle scaled \the\wholewidth
\stopbuffer

\starttext
Thinlines: \thinlines
\processMPbuffer[circle]

Thicklines: \thicklines
\processMPbuffer[circle]

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**Note** For some reason, the above code does not work with MkIV. I don't know why that is the case.